# Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'. Flutter version (3.13.0)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

approximately 1.5 years ago, I developed a multiplatform application. When attempting to run it today, I encountered an error. While I have successfully resolved most of the issues, I am still facing errors when I execute the main.dart file.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart:65:15: Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the class 'ActionCodeInfo'.
 - 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FallThroughError'.
        throw FallThroughError();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.7/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:13:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**Here is my pubspec.yaml file**

```
name: multi_vending_grocery_app
description: Grocery Application

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons:
  dots_indicator:
  fluttertoast:
  firebase_auth: ^3.11.2
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.4
  url_launcher:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.8.0
  provider:
  geolocator:
  google_maps_flutter:
  geocoding: ^2.1.0
  flutter_spinkit:
  shared_preferences:
  carousel_slider:
  get:
  paginate_firestore:
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^5.0.2
  map_launcher:
  flutter_phone_direct_caller:
  expandable_text:
  flutter_easyloading:
  toggle_switch: ^2.1.0
  dotted_border:
  intl:
  chips_choice:
  flutter_credit_card:
  flutter_stripe:
  http:
  progress_dialog_null_safe: ^1.0.7
  flutter_slidable:
  razorpay_flutter:
  search_page:
  lottie:
  firebase_core_web:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Lato
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf

    - family: Anton
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Anton-Regular.ttf

  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**I am unable to fix the code. Experts help me out.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've got an obsolete version of the `firebase-core` package. I had the same problem and this command fixed the issue:

```bash
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```